# quiero añadir automaticamente datos en mi tabla producto al almacen

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo estas tablas de mysql. Es un inventario que registra los productos en otras tablas pero lo principal son estos:

```
   create table registro_producto(
   id_producto int(5) not null,
   id_proveedor int(5) not null,
       id_trabajador int(5) not null,
       nombre_producto varchar(20) not null,
       u_medida varchar(20) not null,
       cantidad_producto decimal(8,3) not null,
       clase_producto varchar(20) not null,
   constraint PK_ID_Producto primary key(id_producto),
   constraint FK_Proveedor1 foreign key (id_proveedor) references proveedor(id_proveedor),
       constraint FK_ID_Trabajador1 foreign key(id_trabajador) references trabajador(id_trabajador),
       constraint CK_Clase_Producto check (clase_Producto in ('perecible','no perecible'))
   );

   create table almacen(
   id_almacen int(5) not null,
       id_producto int(5) not null,
   fecha_entrada date not null,
   cantidad_total decimal(8,3) not null,
   cantidad_restante decimal(8,3),
   constraint pk_id_almacen primary key (id_almacen),
   constraint fk_id_producto foreign key (id_producto) references 
   registro_producto(id_producto)
   );
```

lo que pasa es que quiero crear un trigger para que al momento de registrar un producto en la tabla registrar producto lo haga automaticamente en la tabla almacen que es esta

```
   CREATE TRIGGER tr_actualizar_almacen_registro_producto
   AFTER INSERT ON registro_producto
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       -- Actualizar cantidad total y restante del producto
       UPDATE almacen
       SET cantidad_total = cantidad_total + NEW.cantidad_producto,
           cantidad_restante = cantidad_restante + NEW.cantidad_producto
       WHERE id_producto = NEW.id_producto;
       
       -- Actualizar cantidad restante del producto en base a las entradas anteriores
       UPDATE almacen a
       INNER JOIN (
           SELECT id_producto, SUM(cantidad_producto) AS cantidad_total
           FROM registro_producto
           GROUP BY id_producto
       ) r ON a.id_producto = r.id_producto
       SET a.cantidad_restante = r.cantidad_total - a.cantidad_total;
   END//
DELIMITER ;
```

pero me da error al momento de registrar y si lo hago en la interfas se duplica el item mas no se actualiza el cantidad_total y en cantidad restante no se suma el stock
error 1175

[image: error]

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

si pueden generar el codigo del trigger para ponerlo en mi sistema por favor se los agredeseria

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Qué error te da? Por favor ve a [edit] y añade el error que obtienes al registrar

Comment: sale error 1175 aunque tambien te pediria ayuda si puedo crear otro trigger para ese proposito soy nuevo en esto de mysql

Comment: Y para qué crear otro si tienes ese? No resumas el error, PON el error por favor :)

Comment: hay esta el error bueno la respuesta aunque no se como poner imagenes

Comment: El segundo update no tiene WHERE que lo relacione con el registro NEW. Si MySQL no se quejara, estaríás actualizando TODOS los registros en almacén porque estarías comentiendo el proverbial error de correr UPDATE (o DELETE) sin where...

Comment: @Alfabravo entonses como seria el codigo seria un gran favor ya que e intentado con diferentes forma y nada